# Why I don't receive any report of crashes Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to add Firebase support for my app, and after adding all dependencies I still can't receive any reports. I re-installed my app also and it didn't help me. Where the problem can be? I also will add some other inportant info about my problem but please say me what I have to add for solving this problem.

### UPDATE

My gradle files, project one:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'  // Crashlytics plugin
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            google()
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "..."
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.Singleton.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.droidbond:LoadingButton:0.1.5'

    implementation 'com.samigehi:loadingview:1.1'

    implementation 'io.github.tonnyl:whatsnew:0.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

So, after adding all important scopes to my code I tottaly re-installed my app. It means that I firstly removed it from my device and then installed it again. Maybe the problem is because I re-installed this app on emulator???? And right now I have this picture:

[image]

I can't finish ticked step with number 3. Maybe someone knows where I did mistake?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing what you've done, please post your build.gradle file both app-level and project.

Comment: @jake, I have updated my question, check it please :)

Comment: Have you tried initiating a crash test?

Comment: yes, of course)) it was the first thing which I did :) it didn't help me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this information will help someone else except me)) I have solve this problem with adding some lines to my AndroidManifest to `application` scopes:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
```

this will enable crashlytics at your project also without creating crash. Good Luck :D